# How to let the angular-google-maps load lazily and not break the page if the google-maps-api is not visitable?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, requirejs

I'm using requirejs + angularjs + [angular-google-maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/) to show locations of some house on the map.

On my page, there is a map and some other information, and the other information is more important than the map, so I hope the map can show lazily, even it's OK the map doesn't show for some reason(e.g. can't load google maps api).

My code is like this:

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'app',
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        angular: '../bower_components/angular/angular',
        'angular-google-maps': '../bower_components/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps',
        googlemaps: '../bower_components/googlemaps-amd/src/googlemaps',
        async: '../bower_components/requirejs-plugins/src/async',
        underscore: '../bower_components/underscore/underscore'
    },
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: "angular"
        },
        'angular-google-maps': {
            deps: ['googlemaps!', 'angular', 'underscore']
        }
    }
});

require(['googlemaps!', 'jquery', 'angular', 'angular-google-maps', 'controllers'],
    function (googlemaps, jquery, angular, angularGoogleMaps, controllers) {
        angular.module('app', ['controllers', 'google-maps']);

        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        });
    }
);
```

I used the `googlemaps-amd` library which is a requirejs module and will load google-maps-api-v3 asynchronous, and will wait until the api is loaded successfully.

The `angular-google-maps` module provides an angularjs module named `google-maps`, my main angular module `app` is depend on it.

So in the code, my angularjs code will be executed when google-maps-api-v3 and angular-google-maps all loaded. It's my biggest concern in this question.

The content of `controllers.js`:

**controllers.js**

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    return angular.module('controllers', [])
        .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.hello = "Hello, world";
            $scope.houses = [
                {
                    key: '111',
                    location: {
                        "longitude": 144.99918,
                        "latitude": -37.81859
                    }
                },
                {
                    key: '222',
                    location: {
                        "longitude": 140.99918,
                        "latitude": -40.81859
                    }
                }
            ];

            $scope.map = {
                center: {
                    "longitude": 144.99918,
                    "latitude": -37.81859
                },
                zoom: 13,
                options: {
                    disableDefaultUI: !0,
                    mapTypeControl: !1,
                    tilt: 45
                }
            }
        }])
});
```

It just defined a controller and the data which is needed by map.

And the html:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
hello
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    {{hello}}
    <div ng-if="map">
        <google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options">
            <markers
                    models="houses"
                    idKey="'key'"
                    doRebuildAll="true"
                    doCluster="true"
                    fit="true"
                    coords="'location'">
            </markers>
        </google-map>
    </div>
    {{houses}}
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="../build/main" src="../bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</html>
```

The `../build/main` is packaged and minified one js file, but you can just consider it's the `main.js` I provided in the beginning.

Now the map can be shown correctly, but you know, for some reason, it's very common that google-map-api is blocked or extremely slow sometimes in some country.Then the page is broken totally, you will see placeholders `{{hello}}` and `{{houses}}` shown, even if they are not very related on the map. Which is sadly.

Is it possible to let the angular-google-maps directive load lazily?

And not block other content even if it's very slow or broken?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in place of using {{ variableName }}  you can use  so that the brackets do not show... that would fix that problem.

Otherwise, you will just need to add some try... catch statements to make sure the page doesn't break

Answer (score 0):

In a little side project playing with google maps, I had issues with data being ready before the map was drawn.
I manipulated the map in a promise that was resolved on the maps 'tilesloaded' event.
Something similar should work for you, though I didn't use angular-google-maps...

```
.directive('aMap', function() {
    var mapid = 1;
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.style.width = "100%";
            el.style.height = "100%";
            element.prepend(el);
            var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
                    zoom  : 1
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(el, mapOptions);
            map.id = mapid++;
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
                google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'tilesloaded');
                if ( scope.mapDefer )
                    scope.mapDefer.resolve(map);
                return;
            });
        }
    };
})
.controller('myCtrl', function ($log, $scope, $q, StudyData, mngGeocodeService) {
    $scope.mapDefer = $q.defer();
    $scope.mapDefer.promise
    .then( function ( map ) { drawMap(map) } );

    function drawMap ( map ) {

        mngGeocodeService.get('United States of America')
        .then (
                function ( results, status ) {
                    if ( results.length === 0 )
                        return;
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                            new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest.lat, results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest.lng ),
                            new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lat, results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lng )
                    );
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }
        );

        for ( var i=0; i<StudyData.length; i++ ) {
            addCircle(map, i);
        }
    }
    function addCircle ( map, index ) {
        mngGeocodeService.get(StudyData[index].name)
        .then (
                function ( results, status ) {
                    if ( results.length === 0 )
                        return;
                    var radius = 30000 * Math.sqrt(100/StudyData[index].yearsBetweenAccidents);
                    new google.maps.Circle({
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: '#FF0000',
                        fillOpacity: 0.35,
                        map: map,
                        center: results[0].geometry.location,
                        radius: radius
                    });

                }
        );
    }

    return;
})
```